# Where does this question belong?

Tags: support, closed-questions, off-topic

I asked a [question about Whatsapp](https://superuser.com/questions/1658070/how-to-attach-videos-greater-than-64-mb-in-whatsapp). It wasn't about the mobile version. It's a general question that is relevant to the desktop app as well as the browser version or the mobile app.

But someone thought that it is off-topic and it is now closed. I really want to know the answer to the question. What would be the appropriate forum to ask it?

Comment: Only the desktop version of WhatsApp would be within scope on Super User.  The screenshots you provided within your question are not from the desktop version of WhatsApp.  Additionally, your problem seems like an intentional limitation of WhatsApp itself, a community dedicated to WhatsApp would be a better fit for your question.  The maximum file size for all media is 16 MB and 100 for "regular files'.  WhatsApp specifically and intentionally will not allow a file that exceed those sizes.

Comment: The screenshots are just meant to provide an evidence of file sizes. It is irrelevant from mobile or PC app. The screenshots were taken from the mobile phone just because the desktop app doesn't show the screen size. Also, your information about whatsapp attachments is incomplete at best. I can easily send media up to 64 MB.

Comment: What forum from within the Stackexchange network would be suitable for asking this question?

Comment: It doesn’t belong on this network since those are hard limits.

Comment: Pardon me please, with "this network" do you mean Superuser or the whole Stackexchange limit?